# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Logic

The logic is if an order is cancelled then return 0 otherwise return the owed value - the paid value

Small query

```
CASE WHEN d.cancelled = 'TRUE' 
     THEN '0' 
     ELSE (to_char(b.owed)) - (to_char(d.paid)) 
     END AS balance,
```

Getting the error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 25 Column: 58

Comment: Assuming the to_char function converts the data to a character data from numeric, wouldn't you wnat to do teh subtraction first then the conversion rather than convert and then try to subtract?

Comment: Is your goal to return a `NUMBER` as the balance?  Or a `VARCHAR2`?  Your `THEN` is returning a `VARCHAR2`, your `ELSE` is returning a `NUMBER`.  You'll need to ensure that both paths return a value with the same data type.  It's just not clear which data type you intend to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, either your case should return number or varchar, right now your case return '0' as varchar and else as number. Either both should return a varchar or both should return a number.

**When Both return varchar**

```
CASE WHEN d.cancelled = 'TRUE' 
     THEN '0' 
     ELSE to_char((to_char(b.owed)) - (to_char(d.paid)))
     END AS balance,
```

OR

**When Both return number**

```
CASE WHEN d.cancelled = 'TRUE' 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE (to_char(b.owed)) - (to_char(d.paid))
         END AS balance,
```

OR

**When Both return number**

```
CASE WHEN d.cancelled = 'TRUE' 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE (b.owed - d.paid)
         END AS balance,
```

Answer (score 1):

This `(to_char(b.owed)) - (to_char(d.paid))`  will be a number and `0` is a string. You should remove the ticks in `then`clause or ad a to_char in else clause: `to_char((to_char(b.owed)) - (to_char(d.paid)))` or simply `(b.owed - d.paid)`